# Create a dictionary from a file

Tags: python-3.x

I am creating a code that allows the user to input a .txt file of their choice.  So, for example, if the text read:

"I am you. You ArE I."

I would like my code to create a dictionary that resembles this:
{I: 2, am: 1, you: 2, are: 1}

Having the words in the file appear as the key, and the number of times as the value. Capitalization should be irrelevant, so are = ARE = ArE = arE = etc...

This is my code so far. Any suggestions/help?

```
>> file = input("\n Please select a file")
>> name = open(file, 'r')    
>> dictionary = {}
>> with name:
     >> for line in name:
          >> (key, val) = line.split()
          >> dictionary[int(key)] = val
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the examples in this answer:

[Python : List of dict, if exists increment a dict value, if not append a new dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692388/python-list-of-dict-if-exists-increment-a-dict-value-if-not-append-a-new-dic/1692428#1692428)

You can use `collections.Counter()` to trivially do what you want, but if for some reason you can't use that, you can use a `defaultdict` or even a simple loop to build the dictionary you want.

Here is code that solves your problem.  This will work in Python 3.1 and newer.

```
from collections import Counter
import string

def filter_punctuation(s):
    return ''.join(ch if ch not in string.punctuation else ' ' for ch in s)

def lower_case_words(f):
    for line in f:
        line = filter_punctuation(line)
        for word in line.split():
            yield word.lower()

def count_key(tup):
    """
    key function to make a count dictionary sort into descending order
    by count, then case-insensitive word order when counts are the same.
    tup must be a tuple in the form: (word, count)
    """
    word, count = tup
    return (-count, word.lower())

dictionary = {}

fname = input("\nPlease enter a file name: ")
with open(fname, "rt") as f:
    dictionary = Counter(lower_case_words(f))

print(sorted(dictionary.items(), key=count_key))
```

From your example I could see that you wanted punctuation stripped away.  Since we are going to split the string on white space, I wrote a function that filters punctuation to white space.  That way, if you have a string like `hello,world` this will be split into the words `hello` and `world` when we split on white space.

The function `lower_case_words()` is a generator, and it reads an input file one line at a time and then yields up one word at a time from each line.  This neatly puts our input processing into a tidy "black box" and later we can simply call  `Counter(lower_case_words(f))` and it does the right thing for us.

Of course you don't have to print the dictionary sorted, but I think it looks better this way.  I made the sort order put the highest counts first, and where counts are equal, put the words in alphabetical order.

With your suggested input, this is the resulting output:

```
[('i', 2), ('you', 2), ('am', 1), ('are', 1)]
```

Because of the sorting it always prints in the above order.